# Any simple way to add .profile to ssh?

Tags: ssh

I installed node.js with NVM and it register an additional folder with executables. It **adds new path to the $PATH variable**, and it does it **somewhere in one of `.profile` files**.

So, when I log in via `ssh` manually all works, the `npm` is available. But, **when I try to execute remote script** like `ssh myhost.com "npm install"` **it fails** with `npm not found`.

It happens because when I run **`ssh` remotely it doesn't load the `.profile`**.

Is there an easy way to fix it? I.e. somehow tell `ssh` to use exactly the same env as if I log in manually?

Answer (score 1):

The `.profile` is loaded for login shells as explained in the manual page for bash. You can modify your command to run the login shell:

```
ssh myhost.com "bash -l -c 'npm install'"
```